# How to make base class properties as read only in Derived class?

Tags: c#, oop

In C#, I want to make base class data contract as read only in dervied class and direct access of base class should not be read only.

Comment: What do you have so far? Can you show a short example of your base class and derived class?

Comment: best would be a complete example also of what you want currently what you wrote is a bit confusing

Comment: If I understood the question correctly, you want the base class to have a public settable property and derived class to have it as readonly. If my assumption is true, you are trying to break the meaning of inheritance and not likely a good idea.

Comment: @CarbineCoder I even read it a bit stronger.....that the derived class CAN'T set those properties by itself (only by having an object of the base class it should be possible to set them).

Comment: @Thomas `direct access of base class should not be read only` confused me. I agree private setter is not strictly read-only but I feel OP might have had public setter in his mind :)

Comment: Exactly. public setters but derived classes don't have access to these setters themselves. It is as you stated already not sounding at all like a normal class inheritance and I fear thanks to the formulation of the OPs question that we need him to show an example to be sure what he REALLY means with things (hopefully he will provide one)

Comment: @CarbineCoder , Thomas, 
I Have two Data Contracts as ClassA and ClassB. 
Situation is like , 
 I want ClassA Data Member in ClassB as Read-Only but if i access ClassA direclty it should not be read-only.

 1. If I create object for ClassA, I should be able to set the values to all data members and Save to DB.
 2. If I Create object for ClassB, I should be able to set values only for data members of ClassB and ClassA data members should be read-only.

Comment: @Thomas,CarbineCoder, I Have two Data Contracts as ClassA and ClassB. Situation is like , I want ClassA Data Member in ClassB as Read-Only but if i access ClassA direclty it should not be read-only. 1. If I create object for ClassA, I should be able to set the values to all data members and Save to DB. 2. If I Create object for ClassB, I should be able to set values only for data members of ClassB and ClassA data members should be read-only.

Comment: Then you cannot use inheritance, because you are breaking inheritance.

Comment: @CarbineCoder any other alternative solution for this?

Comment: Its not possible to suggest solution with the current info provided. Give more info on why you want to do this. Sample code would be needed

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by making the setter private in the base class, the getter protected (or public as needed):

```
protected properytype propertyname { get; private set; }
```

Comment: I think this is not what OP wants, he wants the base class to have a public setter

Comment: He wants the base class to have public properties BUT if you derive your class from the base class you should not be able to set those properties from how I understand it. What is missing is an example by the OP so taht we see what he really wants but that is how I read his question

Comment: Let's wait whether the OP gives more details. The question is not quite clear indeed. Since this answers the question how I understood it first, I'll keep the answer for now.